# Defining the order of webjars with Spring Boot and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, webjars

I would like to know if it is possible to define an explicit order of the webjars included in a Spring Boot application (with Spring MVC enabled, of course).

In other words, I have a spring boot project depending on two webjars (webjar1 and webjar2) which include the same resource (that is, example.html is present in both webjar1 and webjar2). When I ask to the server the resource example.html, how could I be sure of the example.html I'm receiving? Is there any way to define that webjar1 is preferred over webjar2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like currently (how do you refer to the webjars)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to rely on ordering.  How are you referencing the files?

Comment: @MarcTarin I have a spring boot server with several webjar dependencies, webjar1, webjar2 and webjar3 (all of them imported from server as maven dependencies). All of the webjars have the same resource (let's say, example.html). When I ask to the server for the resource example.html, it returns the one that is included in the first webjar dependency.

Comment: @MarcTarin In other words, if I define the dependencies in the server in the order webjar1, webjar2 and webjar3, the server answer with the page in webjar1. If I define de dependencies in the order webjar2, webjar1 and webjar3, the server answer with the content of webjar2.

Comment: My problem is that in my real project, I have a Maven webjar dependency (let's say, webjar1) that, transitively, depends on other webjars (let's say, webjar2 and webjar3). Because of the transitivity, it's is difficult to define and exact order.

Comment: @JamesWard I'm not sure whether I've understood your question. All of my webjars are included in my server as maven dependencies (actually, my server depends on a webjar that, transitively, depends on another one).

Comment: How are you asking the server for a resource?  Maybe Spring Boot is collapsing the paths down.

Comment: @JamesWard I'm asking for the resource with the URL http://localhost:8080/myApp/example.html. I suppose you are right and Spring Boot is collapsing the paths, but I would like to have some way to tell Spring MVC that the most important Webjar is one of them (in order to prefer this webjar over the rest of them).

As I told in an above comment, it seems to depend on the order of the webjars in the POM file.

Comment: What is the path you are using to the WebJar asset?  The order in the pom file has nothing to do with the CLASSPATH order which is essentially indeterminate.  So you should not rely on CLASSPATH ordering to solve this.

Comment: @JamesWard I have created a Bitbucket repository with my code at https://bitbucket.org/albegarcia/spring-boot-server-serveral-webjars. I agree with you about the indeterminated classpath order but, I don't know why, the result is different depending on the order you define the webjars dependencies in the pom.xml of the server.

Comment: @JamesWard You can test it for yourself if you want to. With the original code of the repository, package it and run the server. Once the server is running, ask for http://localhost:8080/server/example1.html. You shoud get "Page 1 in webjar1". After that, change the dependencies in server pom.xml (put webjar2 before webjar1), package the project again and restart the server. Now, if you ask for http://localhost:8080/server/example1.html you get "Page 1 in webjar2". Spring boot magic? I would like to know the explanation...

Comment: Thanks for sharing that project!  So you aren't actually using WebJars.  You are serving static assets from the CLASSPATH (which is one way to use actual WebJars).  The assets you are serving all have the same path in the CLASSPATH.  There is no determinant / reliable way to define the ordering for how assets will get pulled out of the CLASSPATH.  The solution that actual WebJars uses is to not have overlapping paths on the CLASSPATH.  That is the only real solution to the problem you are encountering here.

Comment: @JamesWard Thanks for the explanation. What it is really curious is that the result is different depending on the order of the webjars in pom.xml file.

Comment: @JamesWard I tried to analized the generated package by Maven (the  generated executable JAR) and the only two differences I found were: 


1. The own pom.xml file (packaged in META-INF/maven/com.example/server/ directory)
2. The order of the JARs in the packaged JAR (I mean, the executable one generated by Maven. You can see the order, for example, executing "jar tvf server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar").


Because I suppose Spring Boot doesn't analyze pom.xml file in execution time, does it mean that the important thing is the order in the JAR/ZIP file?

Comment: A single JAR can't have the same file.  So the ordering comes from the ordering of the jar files when `java` is executed with a `CLASSPATH` env var or `-cp` flag.  The `pom.xml` does not matter at all at runtime.

Comment: @JamesWard When you generate an executable JAR with a Spring Boot application, it includes several JARs (and compiled classes) inside. It seems that depending on how the individual JARs are included in the executable Spring Boot JAR, the classpath is different. Maybe the key can be at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html, in section E2. It is not totally clear in this entry but I think that depending on the position of the dependies in the JAR/ZIP file, the classpath will be different.

Comment: It looks like `org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher` is responsible for loading the sub-jars.  In which case the ordering must be implemented somewhere in there.  I'm sure you can find a way to control the ordering but a better solution would be to find another mechanism to decide on which resource to load because relying on ordering will be brittle and unportable.

Comment: @JamesWard Totally agree with you. For the moment, my solution is to create a "shaded JAR" (from Spring Boot documentation, "A shaded jar simply packages all classes, from all jars, into a single 'uber jar'") uncompressing all my webjars in a given order.